# MSAccess2010 - show only Add-Ins Tabs

Tags: ms-access

My MS Access apps load a commandBar object at startup in the Add-Ins Tab.
I would like to hide all the others MSAcces Tab. How?

Here the code I use to show the commandbar.

Application.CommandBars("BAMP_WA_Main_Toolbar").Visible = True
Application.CommandBars("BAMP_WA_Main_Toolbar").Position = msoBarTop

The following code found on the web hide all the tabs including the Add-Ins.

DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a table to your database called USysRibbons with three fields - ID (Autonumber), RibbonName (Text) and RibbonXml (Memo).

Add a record to this table and add "MyMenu" to the RibbonName field. In the RibbonXml field add;

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="true">
    <tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabHomeAccess" visible="true" />
    <tab idMso="TabCreate" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabExternalData" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabDatabaseTools" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabSourceControl" visible="false" />
    <tab idMso="TabAddIns" visible="true" />
    </tabs> 
</ribbon>
```

Restart the database and then go to the Access Options and select 'MyMenu' from the Ribbon Name list in the Ribbon and Toolbar options.

Restart again and all the tabs should be hidden apart from 'Addins'.

Comment: Thanks for the input.   I was able to the select 'MyMenu' from the Ribbon Name list in the Ribbon and Toolbar options but the XML content in RibbonXml field not working. Did perform test on a blank database. note: I'm using MSaccess2010. Also I would like the hide the file Tab using VBA when I load an hidden form at startup.

Comment: Sorry missed the closing tag. Add this </customUI> to the end of the xml.

Comment: OK I will check it tomorrow at work. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Does work Thank!   from this [link](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1973858) I was able to hide info under the FILE tabs but not the FILE tab it self.